# Как узнать статус пользователя по discord id?(PyCord)

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

написал вот такой метод, для проверки в сети ли пользователь по ID, но почему то я получаю ошибку: `user не имеет метода status`,хотя исходня из документации такой метод должен быть у discord.Member, я подозреваю что user полученный по fetch_user не такой же как discord.Member вот сам код:

```
@bot.command(name="observe", description="watching the user")
async def kick(ctx, id):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(int(id))
    if user.status == discord.Status.online:
        await ctx.respond("True")
```

(Варианты сделать все по упоминанию не предлагать, мне нужно получать статус именно по ID)

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, вы пытаетесь использовать атрибут **status** объекта **User**, чтобы проверить, находятся ли они в сети, но, похоже, атрибут **status** не является членом класса **User**. Вместо этого вы можете использовать атрибут присутствия для проверки онлайн-статуса пользователя.

Вот как вы можете обновить свой код, чтобы проверить статус пользователя в Сети, используя атрибут присутствия:

```
      @bot.command(name="observe", description="user observation")
async def observe(ctx, id: int):
    member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
    if member is not None:
        if member.status == discord.Status.online:
            await ctx.send("True")
        else:
            await ctx.send("False")
    else:
        await ctx.send("User not found in this server")
```

Comment: user не имеет presence: `Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'presence'`

Comment: Я поменял свой ответ попробуйте написать так

Comment: Я использовал id а не упоминание именно потому что мне нужно проверять статус пользователя которого нет на сервере, так что ваш код мне не подходит